# Can Angular4+ provide localization via HTTP Header Accept_Language?

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-i18n

While reading the [Angular i18n guide](https://angular.io/guide/i18n) I was struck by the following line:

> You need to build and deploy a separate version of the app for each
>   supported language.

It seems like very few system providers would want this model. I know we don't want it. Is there any suggested way of providing localized data via the HTTP Accept_Language header with one system deployed?

Comment: Why not use ngx-translate https://github.com/ngx-translate to provide the i18n for the desired languages?

Comment: @ChristianBenseler - good suggestion. I'd like the full Angular support, but this may help in the short run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now there is no possibility to have a runtime localisation, but it should come in angular 5 update.
Check out the first feature in this link
Runtime i18n (one bundle for all locales with AOT) - [working on it]
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16477